# How to run example TICoreDataSync?

Tags: ticoredatasync

1. I cloned the repository https://github.com/nothirst/TICoreDataSync
2. Create Podfile in TICoreDataSync folder

   pod 'TICoreDataSync'
3. Open terminal

   cd TICoreDataSync

   pod install

The installation was successful and to create a folder pods.

4.I now want to see the work TICoreDataSync/Examples/iOSNotebook/iOSNotebook.iOSNotebook.xcodeproj

But the project has a **9000** error.

If you have someone working example of a fully assembled TICoreDataSync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've had one other CocoaPods error reported recently. Have you tried cloning the repository and using `git submodule update --init --recursive` to clone all the submodules? That should give you a working repo.